# Help understanding the Tensorboard histogram names and meaning in an LSTM Model

Tags: keras, tensorflow, lstm

Can someone please help me understand what the names and shapes of the following tensorboard histogram outputs mean about an LSTM model I coded? Thank you!

I understand the terms in the names like bias, gradients, LSTM etc. I do not understand what they are saying about the LSTM model with 3 cells. The LSTM model trains really well with no underfitting or overfitting.

Happy to provide any additional information, please ask!

Model Summary:

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 3)                 408

---

LSTM Model in keras:
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(3, input_shape=(1,30)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

Tensorboard output of histograms:
[image: dense_1-bias_0]
[image: dense_1-bias_0_grad]
[image: dense_1-kernel_0]
[image: dense_1-kernel_gradient]
[image: dense_1-out]
[image: lstm_1-bias_0]
[image: lstm_1-bias_0-grad]
[image: lstm_1-kernel_0]

Any help is much appreciated.